# How to add Dynamic key name and value in Encodable(Swift)?

Tags: swift, codable, encodable

I have a very simple request:

```
{"token": "abcd", "key": "value" }
```

I'm trying to add this request as an `Encodable`. Now, here the issue arises that the `key` name can be anything like "123", "311", the type of the key will be `String`, but it's name is dynamic. How can I add dynamic names in Encodable?

```
struct Answers: Encodable {
  let token: String 
  let key: String 
}
```

I tried using generics, but it didn't work. Any one have any idea?

Comment: And how do you identify what is the name?

Comment: @PGDev I receive an id value for the question and that value I use for name.

Comment: Are you Decoding as well? Or using the above request directly?

Comment: No, I will decode but that will be a different `struct`, this `struct` is just for the request.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `Codable` allows that kind of functionality currently. You can't create a `Codable` type with *dynamic keys* as of now.

Alternatively, if this is the model you're using, you can simply create a `Dictionary` from it and then encode it using `JSONEncoder()`.

**Example:**

```
let dict = ["token": "abcd", "1234": "value"]
do {
    let response = try JSONEncoder().encode(dict)
    print(response)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am doing the same thing currently, I thought may be there will be a way to handle dynamic keys.

Comment: @Rob Unfortunately there is not. May be we'll get this in future Do accept if the answer helped. Happy Coding 

Answer (score 0):

Rob,

If you could change the JSON response you can use something like that `{token: "AAA", data: {"key":"123"}}`.

So you can create

```swift
struct Response<DataType: Codable>: Codable { 
    let token: String
    let data: DataType
}
```

With this `Struct`, you can pass many combinations of dynamic values.

My solution doesn't work with your actual data, but maybe you can talk with the team about API and maybe change the data.

Comment: Nice, you are welcome! Feel free to ask if you want